# How does child_process spawn capture python output in real time

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am learning vscode plugin development and I want to know if spawn can get the output in real time.

I run the following code.

```
        const { spawn } = require('child_process');
        const child = spawn('python', ['test.py'], { cwd: 'path' });
        child.stdout.on('data', (data: Uint8Array) => {
            console.log(data.toString());
        });
        child.stderr.on('data', (data: Uint8Array) => {
            console.log(data.toString());
        });
        child.on('close', (code: number) => {
            console.log(` ${code}`);

        });
```

test.py

```
import sys
import time

sys.stdout.write('stdout 1\n')
time.sleep(1)
sys.stderr.write('stderr 1\n')
time.sleep(2)
sys.stdout.write('stdout 2\n')
time.sleep(3)
sys.stderr.write('stderr 2\n')
```

output

```
stderr 1
stderr 2

stdout 1
stdout 2
0
```

What I want is to be able to get the output in order.
I tested it is normal to capture the output of the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of python's buffering, just call python and add -u parameter